# In a JavaScript object literal, should i refer to 'this' or the variable name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was having issues in my object literal using `this`, but when changing to the name of the object variable itself, my problems went.

When using this, I was getting a **'myFunction' is not a function** error.

Should I be doing this:

```
var app = {

    init: function() {

        this.myFunction();

    },

    myFunction: function() {

        return "Hello world!";

    }

};
```

Or, this?

```
var app = {

    init: function() {

        app.myFunction();

    },

    myFunction: function() {

        return "Hello world!";

    }

};
```

What is the correct way to do this?

This particular example is a very simplified version of my problem and may not reproduce the same issues, but it's the same general pattern I was following, where functions would call each other using `this`.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Both are good, you need to use app.method when 'this' might correspond to a different context (a method context) but you want to access app

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct way to do this?

Both are correct, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

If you're only ever going to have one of these and you're not going to copy those methods to any other objects (which you can do in JavaScript), then using `app` probably makes more sense.

My guess is that the problem you were having when you were using `this` was that you'd done something like this:

```
somethingThatAcceptsACallback(app.init);
```

or

```
someElement.onclick = app.init;
```

...and when `init` was called, it couldn't call `myFunction`. That's because in JavaScript (for now), the way `this` is set mostly depends on *how a function is called*, not where the function is defined. In both of the above cases, although a reference to the *function* is given to the other code, when the other code calls it, it doesn't do anything to set `this` to `app`.

You can use ES5's `Function#bind` (which can be shimmed on IE8 and older) to create functions that, when called, call the original function with the correct `this` value:

```
somethingThatAcceptsACallback(app.init.bind(app));
```

or

```
someElement.onclick = app.init.bind(app);
```

But again, if `app` is a one-off, just using `app` within your functions is fine.

More about `this` *(on my blog)*:

- [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Answer (score 0):

in your first code **this** refers and **app** refers same. In my point of view I can suggest

```
var app = {    
    init: function() {    
        app.myFunction();   
    },   
    myFunction: function() {    
        return "Hello world!";    
    }   
};
```

this code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `this` changes depending on how the function is called. This problem is often gotten around by creating a variable named `self` which is assigned the value of `this` at a stage when you know positively the value of `this`

```
var app = {
    self: this,
    init: function() {

        self.myFunction();

    },
    myFunction: function() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
};
```